# Deserialization gives ClassCastException

Tags: serialization, deserialization, classcastexception

I have two packages, one for client and one for server. The Message.java file is present in both  packages.

```
//  Message.java
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Message implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //*** This line is present only   on  server side.
public String type, sender, content, recipient;
public Message(String type, String sender, String content, String recipient){
    this.type = type;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.content = content;
    this.recipient = recipient;
}

public String toString(){
    return "{type='"+type+"', sender='"+sender+"', content='"+content+"', recipient='"+recipient+"'}";
}
}
```

On Client side i have the following code

```
public void send(Message msg){
try{
        Out.writeObject(msg);
        Out.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception SocketClient send()");
    }
}
```

On server side i have the following code

```
public void run(){  
    while (true){  
        try{  
           Message msg = (Message) streamIn.readObject();
        }
        catch(Exception ioe){  
            System.out.println(ID + " ERROR reading: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

On line  "Message msg = (Message) streamIn.readObject();" on server side iam getting 
"ClassCastException". Please help, as i am stuck here !

Comment: A quick stab in the dark: Did you check your imports, if you imported the right Message-class? That kind of mistakes happens to me occasionally.

Comment: Thank @Layna, it worked. I wrote "import com.client.Message;". But i want to know why i have to import it on the server side? I already have a Message.java on the server side and i want to typecast the client Message object(streamIn.readObject()) to  the server Message class reference.